# How to change password for logged in user

Tags: php, codeigniter, change-password

Is there any solution how to make change password for logged in user? i want to make a change password for logged in user, the code i made only change user password with user id number 1. it doesn't change for logged in user. so any idea?

this is my controller:

```
    public function update(){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Current Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newpass', 'New Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('confpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]|max_length[20]');

if($this->form_validation->run()){
    $cur_password = $this->input->post('password');
    $new_password = $this->input->post('newpass');
    $conf_password = $this->input->post('confpassword');
    $this->load->model('queries');
    $userid = '1';
    $passwd = $this->queries->getCurrPassword($userid);
    if($passwd->password == $cur_password){
        if($new_password == $conf_password){
            if($this->queries->updatePassword($new_password, $userid)){
                echo 'Password updated successfully';
            }
            else{
                echo 'Failed to update password';
            }
        }
        else{
            echo 'New password & Confirm password is not matching';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo'Sorry! Current password is not matching';
   }
}else{
echo validation_errors();
}
```

This is my model:

```
public function getCurrPassword($userid){
 $query = $this->db->where(['id'=>$userid])
                ->get('users');
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->row();
} }
 public function updatePassword($new_password, $userid){
$data = array(
  'password'=> $new_password
  );
  return $this->db->where('id', $userid)
                  ->update('users', $data); }
```

Comment: What framework is this? Seems like an awful lot of convoluted programming to simply change a password.

Comment: Well, that's because you have $userid = '1'; in your if block.

Comment: codeigniter @EdwardB.

Comment: So is there any solution dude? @Vagabond

Comment: Yes, get the user id of the current logged in user instead of hardcoding it to `1`. The current user's id will probably be in `$_SESSION` somewhere.

Comment: How do you intend to pass the user id to the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

When someone logs in, you must set a `$_SESSION` to store your user information, such as username, id, email,... to use when you need. Then you can check the `$_SESSION['session_name']['id']` to change user password. `$_SESSION` is important and must be set when user logs in.